Why does a Compact Flash card adapter appear to not be working in the ThinkPad 760 EL?
I have a couple laptops from IBM, both early Pentiums (one MMX other just Pentium), and I tried to use a standard Compact Flash to IDE adapter, however there are 4 pins that I think are the drive select that aren't on the adapter I have. I have since found out these are for extra power.
I used a virtual machine and have the Compact Flash card setup with a Windows 95 boot sector, and it works there. However, when I plug this adapter into the laptop, the laptop does not go past post and RAM check. Even with a bootable, known good diskette in the drive.
This machine boots just fine from the original HDD, I just cannot get this Compact Flash card to work on it.
I ordered a different adapter and I am hoping that fixes it.
https://www.reddit.com/r/vintagecomputing/comments/1fksula/ibm_thinkpad_760el_cf_adaptor/
HDD in Adapter:

Drive:

Drive pile:

CF card:

CF card 2:


The 4 pins extra are power - 44 pin IDE/laptop drives included it unlike desktop 40 pin connectors

Why are you messing around with Compact Flash? The drives clearly have PATA connectors; PATA has nothing to do with SCSI. PATA is basically IDE.

“Parallel ATA (PATA), originally AT Attachment, also known as Integrated Drive Electronics (IDE), is a standard interface designed for IBM PC-compatible computers.”

I would say these are PATA 2.5" drives and there are many adapters out there to connect a PATA drive to your computer via USB.
If, instead. you want to hook up Compact Flash cards to a PATA interface such devices exist; like from this site. They are not as common as PATA to USB connectors but they do exist.


Isn't that a garden variety 44 pin IDE/pata connector? Iirc CF was electrically identical to it and could be simply adapted passively. I think OP is confused by the built in power. Damn I feel old now

I am in fact 19 lol, I run a college club about vintage computing and I am trying to learn as much as I can by messing around with everything.  I was only confused because the computer does not boot when the CF card is in...not even from floppy
